# If someone's reputations come back to below 15

Tags: discussion, votes, reputation

AYK, A user can up-vote or down-vote posts when they reach the threshold of 15 reps. If they have lower reps their votes will be recorded until they reach the required threshold.

My question is that if someone's reputations come back to below that 15 threshold, will their votes get erased?

If yes, is this fair for the post-owners who have received those votes when the voters had at least 15 reps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, those votes won't be erased. Votes are only erased in case of [voting fraud](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/295232) (massively voting on posts from specific other users) and when a user deletes their account.

I looked for an authoritative answer on Meta Stack Exchange but all I could find was [Do votes get canceled if voting privilege is lost?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278179/295232).

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please explain more about voting frauds? How are these massive votings done?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/295232

Comment: Thank you. BTW, now I reached 15 reps in the main site, but I don't know why it remained 13 here.

Comment: Caching, you have to wait an hour or so.

Comment: Why is this delay required?

Comment: Performance reasons. Sorry for the short answer, I don't know the details.